# Java/Android SDK with only .class files?

Tags: java, android, sdk

I am currently working on a project at work and have been given a developer SDK which only has .class files in it. It is for the development of an android/ROS robot.
I am new to Java, and am unsure how to get started developing with these .class files. Unfortunately there is no documentation.
Should there be .java files, or should I be able to use these to start, and how do I do that?

Thank you so much for you help.

Brendan

Comment: Add the directory as dependency in your IDE of choice.

Comment: Thank you so much @JohannesKuhn . Knew it would be something simple!